# Dynamic CSS Vs Inline Issues in Code any Way around in a Wordpress Themes?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

One of my Developer has used this kind of Code to style -

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped custom-color-progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $percentage?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $percentage * 100?>%"></div>
```

Bu few experts believes that this  -

```
style="width:<?php echo $percentage * 100?>%"
```

looks ultimately hard coded(or Inline CSS in Browser) and is not what one may look into the Professional themes.

Here is what my developers thinks - 
Their is no other way round and this is the only way as their are various instances where CSS value is stored in a Database(or variable) through Theme Option Panel.

However when expert designer and Critique belive that their should be some better way around to avoid this inline CSS even though it is coming dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well another solution would be to use **[`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style)** which affords you an opportunity to inject dynamic inline styles:

```
function my_custom_style() {

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'custom-style',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-style.css'
    );

    //our customer percentage set by a user in some options panel
    $percentage = get_theme_mod('my-custom-percentage');

    $inline_style =<<<DOC

    .progress-bar {
        width: {$percentage}%;
    }

DOC;   

    //inject our custom percentage after "custom-style.css"
    wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $inline_style );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_style');
```

Aside from that, when a user changes settings in the backend it is also possible to generate a css file programmatically, storing it somewhere in the uploads directory and then dynamically enqueueing that file using **[`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)**.

You can also hook onto **[`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head)** and inject your styles that way too although probably not the best way, but here's an example just for the sake of it:

```
function my_custom_style() {

    $percentage = get_theme_mod('my-custom-percentage');

    ?>

    <style type="text/css">
        .progress-bar {
            width: <?php echo $percentage; ?>%;
        }
    </style>

    <?php

}

add_action('wp_head', 'my_custom_style', 100);
```

Comment: 1. I am still not trained that much, but I am reading all that you mentioned above to absorb this all. I have something more to add infact few more questions - 

When you use Theme Options then their are various instances where CSS such as: Font, Color, Font-weight etc is used at so many instances. In that case do one need to Create functions separately so many times or their is a better way to do it all.

Comment: 2. Please shed more light on this -
Aside from that, when a user changes settings in the backend it is also possible to generate a css file programmatically, storing it somewhere in the uploads directory and then dynamically enqueueing that file using wp_enqueue_scripts

Can you site an example? I searched on internet and couldn't find an example of the thing mentioned above.